How to add excludecodecoverage attribute at namespace level?
I have one project which containg 3 foplders Models, Services and Core where in models folders contains POCO class which i dont want to include part of coverege so how can we do that? I know that individual class level we can assign [ExcludeCodeCoverage] attribute but how we can achieve at namespace level.
Project is developed in .Net 6
